# How to prevent users from accessing files directly from url?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url

I have a php file called `home.php` that uses `main.php` in its code. Both are in the same directory. I don't want people from accessing `main.php` by typing it in the url like: http://localhost/main.php

The code in .htaccess is:

```
<Files main.php>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Files>
```

But this is preventing `home.php` also from accessing `main.php`.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You try to fix a symptom instead of fixing the cause. Read a bit about how modern web applications work, about a "controller" that serves all requests. Today's web applications to not expose physical files via a http server, but an application. There are endless examples you can take a look at, search for MVC maybe, or "php router", or similar.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This One**

You can add lines to `.htaccess` file

```
Deny from all
ErrorDocument 403 "nothing is here"
```

It will display the "nothing is here" message in case of the unauthorised access.

If you want to redirect by an error code to a certain page then you can define a command as follows:

```
ErrorDocument 404 "/errors/404.html"
```

It will redirect to the `/errors/404.html` and show the custom page not found screen.

Comment: how do i do it using .htaccess?

Comment: This is not allowing localhost also to access the files